# How to implement a true Master-Detail in XAF using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xaf

I have a master-detail scenario in XAF using Entity Framework. I've annotated the `Master.Details` property with `[Aggregated]`.

I expect two functionality:

- Detail objects removes if the master is deleted.
- If some details are added to master, they should save when the master saves.

But unfortunately it is not acting like that. Every time I click on the new button on the detail grid, it creates detail and saves it to database.

Also I found this old question (2 years ago) says that this problem exists with EF.
https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q557784

Is there any workaround to have true composition and master detail using EF?

Answer (score 0):

In XAF, records are not physically deleted from the database. Instead, they are marked as deleted using the GCRecord column. When this field is **not null**, the row is considered as deleted and will never be shown in your application.

Also, as soon as you instantiate an object, it'll be saved into the database, with a non null GCRecord if you deleted it before your call to CommitChanges.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I think you're talking about XPO, which is not my case. I'm working with EF.

Answer (score 0):

I find the [Aggregated] property is not necessary with EF

The trick is to set the relationship up in the DBContext OnModelCreating

Using Sales Orders as an example

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Order>().HasMany(x => x.Lines).WithOptional(x => x.Order).WillCascadeOnDelete();
    }
```

// How I wish I could use WithRequired here, but XAF does not support it.

Make sure that LinkNewObjectToParentImmediately is true.

```
 public partial class T474565WindowsFormsApplication : WinApplication {
    public T474565WindowsFormsApplication() {
        InitializeComponent();
      //  LinkNewObjectToParentImmediately = false;
    }
```

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T474565